# Точность формулировок

Tags: грамотная-речь

В каком случае можно использовать выражение "пожарная безопасность". а в каком - "противопожарная безопасность"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***пожарная безопасность.***

Из словаря:

**БЕЗОПАСНЫЙ,** (для кого-чего). 1. Не угрожающий опасностью, лишённый угрозы. Б-ые дороги. Укрыться в безопасном месте. Обстановка в городе безопасна. **<Безопасность,** -и; ж. Почувствовать себя в полной безопасности. **Обеспечение пожарной безопасности.**

Ошибка связана со смешением понятий:

ПРОТИВОПОЖАРНЫЙ,  Предназначенный для тушения или предупреждения пожара. **П-ые мероприятия. П-ая техника. П-ые средства.**

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/241147

Противопожарная безопасность

Пожарная безопасность — это состояние защищенности личности, имущества, общества и государства от пожаров.

«Противопожарная безопасность» — **неграмотное словосочетание,** которое встречается для обозначения «пожарной безопасности».

Answer (score 0):

Когда наши сотрудники готовили свои должностные инструкции, клерки из юр бюро настаивали на "противопожарная безопасность". 
На мой взгляд, этот вариант больше подходит поджигателям!